# google play game services and user id

Tags: android, google-play, google-plus, google-play-services

I am developing an android game. I implemented a google plus login feature so I can access user's information. On the other hand, a defferent sign in objects are used for google play games services to work, specifically saving games.
Is there a way to connect to google services and get the users name and a unique id?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution, a little tricky.
Here is how to obtain the `Person` object and the account name:

```
Person person = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
```